# Recursive function check(s) that take a string representing a password as input and returns all the characters that are digits ( 0 -9)

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem which is below and my code. I could use some help.

Write a recursive function check(s) that take a string representing a password as input and returns all the characters that are digits (0 -9)

```
def check(s):
    if not s.idigit():
        return
    else:
        return check(s.isdigit())
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile.  Also, you haven't shown any examples of what it does vs. what you want it to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ''
    elif s[0].isdigit():
        return s[0] + check(s[1:])
    else:
        return check(s[1:])
```

For the example

```
print(repr(check('12a3z-4!')))
```

this prints

```
'1234'
```

which is what you want. There are other ways to write this code but this is probably simplest for a beginner in Python.

---

From your last comment, you may want to print out the digits in the password, from largest to smallest, each on a separate line, and you don't care about returning anything from a function. If that's what you want, try

```
def check(s):
    if len(s) > 0:
        check(s[1:])
        if s[0].isdigit():
            print(s[0])

check('31a4z-2!')
```

This prints

```
2
4
1
3
```

Comment: it works but i need it to  return all numbers that check for not just one.

Comment: @JessePizano: please post a MCVE, as mentioned in my first comment.  Show where your version of Rory's code fails for you.

Comment: im sorry i apologize it works one more other thing i dont know if make a difference but how can it make it print from largest number to lowest? when it checks

Comment: @JessePizano: You could call `sorted(check(s), reverse=True)` which will give you a list of the numbers, starting with the lowest. If you want that as a string you can use `''.join(sorted(check(s), reverse=True))`.

Comment: ok im sorry to keep bothering this is all new to me so how will i rewrite the code so it would print the digits from the last to frist when it checks. Again thank you so much

Comment: What do you mean "last to first"? Do you mean "largest to smallest" as in your previous comment, or "last included in the password to first included in the password"?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion has two main parts:

1. Base case: what to return when you hit the most trivial input.
2. Recursion case: how to reduce the problem to something simpler.

Here, your base case is

```
if s == '':
    return ''
```

Your recursion case depends on whether or not the leading character is a digit.  If it is, you want to add it to the string you build; if not, you have nothing to add.  Either way, you call your routine on the remainder of the string:

```
add = ''
if s[0].isdigit():
    add = s[0]
```

After this, call the routine on the rest of the string.  When that returns, combine its return value with **add**, and return *that* to the calling program.

Does that move you along?